# set costs for orders in or-tools

Tags: python, or-tools, vehicle-routing

We minimize the fuel consumed by the vehicles in terms of cost. Some customers may sometimes need an extra staff member while purchasing their products. These extra staffs have a fixed daily cost. This cost + fuel consumption should be minimized.

In the products you see in the figure, those with a code of 1 need extra staff in the car.

[image]

If those with 1 code go more in the same car and if there is no 1 code in other cars, they do not need staff and no extra money is paid for that person. This is not a necessity of course, but the aim is to minimize the total cost spent.

Note: If there is 1 product that needs even one extra person in the car, an extra fee will be paid. (extra $50 cost will be if there's an extra person in the car)

Here is how I calculate vehicle costs.

```
data['costs'] = [0.2314,0.158,0.132,0.201]
number_of_vehicles = 4
for vehicle_id in range(number_of_vehicles):
    routing.SetFixedCostOfVehicle(data['costs'][vehicle_id], vehicle_id)
```

Answer (score 0):

So basically if a vehicle visit a node which require a staff member you want to add a cost of 50 to the objective ?

Proposal in 3 steps:

- Count number of staff needed locations which have been visited;
- Transform this value in range [0, 1] at each end node.
- Add a penalty cost to the objective if this value is 1.

1. first I would add a dimension "staff_count" which is increased by 1 each time you visit a location which need a staff.
   (see capacity example: https://developers.google.com/optimization/routing/cvrp#python_1)

```py
staff_cost = [...., 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1] # from 0..., 101 to 110

def staff_counter_callback(from_index):
  """Returns if staff is needed for this node."""
  # Convert from routing variable Index to demands NodeIndex.
  node = manager.NodeToIndex(from_index)
  return staff_cost[node]

staff_counter_callback_id = routing.RegisterUnaryTransitCallback(
staff_counter_callback)

dimension_name = "staff_counter"
routing.AddDimension(
 staff_counter_callback_id,
 0, # no slack
 N, # don't care just big enough so we won't reach it
 True, # force it to zero at start
 dimension_name
)
staff_counter_dimension = routing.GetDimensionOrDie(dimension_name)
```

2. Second I'll create a second dimension "staff_used" (between 0,1) whose end node is 1 iif
   end node of the "staff" dimension is > zero.
   note: you can see it as a boolean set to 1 if we need a staff along the route, 0 otherwise

```py
dimension_name = "staff_used"
routing.AddConstantDimensionWithSlack(
 0, # transit is 0 everywhere
 1, # capacity will be 0 everywhere and maybe 1 on end node
 1, # need slack to allow transition to 1 in end node
 True, # force it to zero at start
 dimension_name
)
staff_dimension = routing.GetDimensionOrDie(dimension_name)

solver = routing.solver()
for vehicle_id in range(manager.GetNumberOfVehicles()):
  index = routing.End(vehicle_id)
  # the following expr will resolve to 1 iff staff has been required along the route 
  expr = staff_counter_dimension.CumulVar(index) > 0
  solver.Add(expr == staff_dimension.CumulVar(index))
```

note: please notice that `AddConstantDimensionWithSlack()` has slack and capacity parameter swapped, I'm sorry for this API consistent issue...
ref: https://github.com/google/or-tools/blob/b37d9c786b69128f3505f15beca09e89bf078a89/ortools/constraint_solver/routing.h#L457-L467

3. Third, use `RoutingDimension::SetCumulVarSoftUpperBound`, with upper bound 0 and penalty 50 on each **end** node of this second dimension.
   note: Idea pay 50 if `staff_used_dimension.CumulVar(end_node) == 1`

```py
for vehicle_id in range(manager.GetNumberOfVehicles()):
  index = routing.End(vehicle_id)
  staff_dimension.SetCumulVarSoftUpperBound(index, 0, 50)
```

ref: https://github.com/google/or-tools/blob/b37d9c786b69128f3505f15beca09e89bf078a89/ortools/constraint_solver/routing.h#L2514-L2523

### Annexe

If you want to limit the total number of vehicles having an extra worker to N you can use:

```py
solver = routing.solver()
staff_at_end = []
for vehicle_id in range(manager.GetNumberOfVehicles()):
  index = routing.End(vehicle_id)
  staff_at_end.append(staff_dimension.CumulVar(index))

solver.Add(solver.Sum(staff_at_end) <= N)
```